# NHibernate - how to configure associations not to use primary key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working with a legacy database put together by some very strange people. I'm writing an NHibernate DAL over the top of it but running into some odd mapping scenarios.

In one example, I have a table with a number of fields including `LE_RECNUM` (integer primary key) and `LE_CODE` (string).

However, all relationships throughout the database join onto `LE_CODE`, not `LE_RECNUM`, for some unfathomable reason.

I need to specify that `LE_RECNUM` is the Id in my mapping file, because I need the primary key to be generated when I insert records. However, I want all associations to use `LE_CODE` instead of `LE_RECNUM`.

Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
References(x => x.SomeProperty).Column("LE_CODE").PropertyRef(x => x.SomePropertyInParent);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been reading the documentation and I don't really get what this property-ref mapping thing was originally for. Are there any consequences I should be aware of?

Comment: Thanks again. I was surprised that the Linq provider didn't retrieve parent and child in the same query. but since the association is only one way (from child to parent), I don't risk N+1.

Comment: Thank you very much sir you are great